# The set of all infinitely often differentiable functions?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, functional-analysis, ring-theory

Consider the set of all functions $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$

Let us define the infinite subset $D$ of that set such that it is of maximal size and $f \in D$ if $f$ is continuous and differentiable and $f ^ \prime $ is also in $D$.

That is, $D$ contains all functions that can be differentiated (or integrated) any number of times and still remain continuous and differentiable.

I think $D$ contains at least (for example) all the polynomials, the exponential function, sine and cosine, and is closed under addition and multiplication, but not division.  I suspect it is at least a ring. (but am not 100% sure.  I think of course $f(x) = 0$ is the additive identitiy, $f(x) = 1$ the multiplicative identity. $g(x) = -f(x)$ is additive inverse of $f(x)$)

Questions:

- Does D have a name?  Are there papers about it or something similar?
- Is there some better way of describing its elements?
- Does its elements have any interesting properties that are not immediately obvious?

Comment: This is the vector space $C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ of infinitely often differentiable functions.

Comment: @Andrew Tomazos You are correct that the usual addition and multiplication of functions endow $D = C^{\infty}(\Bbb R)$ with a ring structure. Its maximal ideals are $I_a := \{f : f(a) = 0\}$, $a \in \Bbb R$.

Comment: @JensSchwaiger: There is a paper here that uses the term "infinitely often differentiable function" http://ftp.math.uni-rostock.de/pub/romako/heft59/kru59.pdf

Comment: See https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/often

Comment: Smooth functions. Yes they form a vector space. Even an algebra because the product of smooth functions is smooth.

Comment: @T_M: I think you mean "smooth" in this sense: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothness  That article describes this set as "infinitely differentiable" and is the **C-infinity functions** (or $C^\infty$ functions)

Comment: The wiki article says: "At the very minimum, a function could be considered smooth if it is differentiable everywhere " (I don't quite understand the phrasing 'at the very minimum') I was actually a bit surprised that the article didn't state more clearly that when mathematicians say "smooth" in a pure math context, they really (pretty much always) mean infinitely differentiable. e.g. A polynomial is a smooth function. Smooth manifold. or e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mollifier "mollifiers are smooth functions" etc.